# D3: two x-axis with independent zoom behavior

Tags: d3.js

I want to have two independent x-axis in my Time-Comparison chart (TimeScale) and have a problem to implement the zoom Behavior for both. I would like that d3 calculates the x-Domain for both axis independently - that would be perfect. But how can I bind (and call) two zoom Behavior for each axis to my one 'g'-Element (.d3-draw-area) ?

I have listener for both axis but only the "Master-Axis" is (logically) being computed:

```
d3.select(".d3-draw-area").call(d3.behavior.zoom()
            .on('zoom' + ".x" + self._getXAxisMaster().ID, function () { self._zoomX(self._getXAxisMaster()); })
            .on('zoom' + ".x" + self._getXAxisSlave().ID, function () { self._zoomX(self._getXAxisSlave()); })
            .x(self._getXAxisMaster().d3Axis.scale())
            );
```

thx...!

Comment: and how do you want to trigger the zoom action for each axis? do these get triggered together (say a same pinch/pan action impacts both axis) or is it independent i.e. pinch changes one axis and pan changes another?

Comment: zoom Action together and pan action independent (to adjust the time offset)

Comment: ok. One of the ways is to separate the call() for each zoom behavior and add it on different elements (create hidden overlapping areas for d3-draw-area). Right now you are chaining zoom behavior and it doesn't work this way.

Comment: Let me know if you need a code sample... or share a fiddle of your code and we can look it up.

Comment: ah ok, overlapping areas with multiple zoom behavior calls (?) you have a little code sample ready ? that would be great. thank you!

Comment: @TaranJ please, can you give me a little kick to create hidden overlapping svg areas (to bound more than one zoom behavior) - I do not know how to implement this. thank you!

Comment: hey... lemme write a quick sample... but unless you share sample data set or a working example I cant be clear on what you want. so maybe you can customize my code for ur need... I'll can share how you can have multiple x axis which work independently on pan/drag action [ pan up/down for one axis and pan left/right for second axis ], and zoom will impact both x axis.

Comment: I'm in a large project and just trying to organize a test access for demo. 
Better than to extract the code. Primarily would be important to me to know how to implement two hidden overlapping areas (equivalent) to bind two zoom behavior. thanks

Comment: I'm not able to make the master, slave dual scales single domain work independently. So I put the second scale on y domain and plotted the chart as dual x axis. Other sample I am posting below is incase there is a relation between master and slave scale (since you mentioned an offset correction).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not able to make the master-slave independent scales work on a single domain (x). In the code above, you have specified masterScale on the domain (x), so only master scale gets triggered. Also I'm not able to understand the kind of data you are plotting, or what is the relation between master/slave scales. Check out below code and see if any of these work for you:

1) For 2 independent scales and 2 independent dimension (properties or attributes) in your data, you can convert y axis to a secondary x-axis.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/8phcu9w6/1/)

```
  var data = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    data.push([Math.random(), Math.random()]);
  }
  d3.select('#chart')
  .append("svg").attr("width", window.innerWidth).attr("height",window.innerHeight)
  .datum(data).call(init());

  function init() {
    var svg, margin = {top: 60,bottom: 80,left: 60,right: 0}, width = 500, height = 400,
      xaxis1 = d3.svg.axis(), xaxis2 = d3.svg.axis(), 
    scaleOne = d3.scale.linear(), scaleTwo = d3.scale.linear(), zoomable = true,
    zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().x(scaleOne).y(scaleTwo).on("zoom", zoomable ? draw : null);

    svg = d3.select('svg').data([data]);
    svg.enter().append('svg');
    var g = svg.append('g').attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        g.append("defs").append("clipPath")
          .attr("id", "clip")
          .append("rect")
          .attr("width", width - margin.left - margin.right)
          .attr("height", height - margin.top - margin.bottom);

        g.append("svg:rect")
          .attr("class", "border")
          .attr("width", width - margin.left - margin.right)
          .attr("height", height - margin.top - margin.bottom)
          .style("stroke", "black")
          .style("fill", "none");

        g.append("g").attr("class", "axis One")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + (height - margin.top - margin.bottom) + ")");

        g.append("g").attr("class", "axis Two")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + (height - margin.top - margin.bottom + 60) + ")");

        g.append("g")
          .attr("class", "scatter")
          .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");

        g.append("svg:rect")
          .attr("class", "zoom box")
          .attr("width", width - margin.left - margin.right)
          .attr("height", height - margin.top - margin.bottom)
          .style("visibility", "hidden")
          .attr("pointer-events", "all")
          .call(zoom);

        scaleOne.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
          return d[0];
        })).range([0, width - margin.left - margin.right]);

        xaxis1.scale(scaleOne).orient('bottom').tickPadding(10);
        svg.select('g.axis.One').call(xaxis1);

        scaleTwo.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
          return d[1];
        })).range([0, width - margin.left - margin.right]);

        xaxis2.scale(scaleTwo).orient('bottom').tickPadding(10);
        svg.select('g.axis.Two').call(xaxis2);
        draw();

    function update() {
      var gs = svg.select("g.scatter");

      var circle = gs.selectAll("circle")
        .data(function(d) {
          return d;
        });

      circle.enter().append("svg:circle")
        .attr("class", "points")
        .style("fill", "steelblue")
        .attr("cx", function(d) {
          return X1(d);
        }).attr("cy", function(d) {
          return X2(d);
        }).attr("r", 4);

      circle.attr("cx", function(d) {
        return X1(d);
      }).attr("cy", function(d) {
          return X2(d);
        });

      circle.exit().remove();
    }

    function zoom_update() {
      zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
        .x(scaleOne)
        .y(scaleTwo)
        .on("zoom", zoomable ? draw : null);
      svg.select('rect.zoom.box').call(zoom);
    }

    function draw() {
      svg.select('g.axis.One').call(xaxis1);
      svg.select('g.axis.Two').call(xaxis2);
      update();
      zoom_update();
    };
    function X1(d) {
      return scaleOne(d[0]);
    }
    function X2(d) {
      return scaleTwo(d[1]);
    }
    return chart;
  }
```

2) Incase you have connected/dependent scales, you can apply same scale on 2 axis and generate the offset correction (even a logarithmic correction) and have dual axis on same domain. This one keeps your y domain/axis available to plot another dimension in your data.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/4v6ssws4/)

```
  var data = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    data.push([Math.random(), Math.random()]);
  }
  d3.select('#chart')
  .append("svg").attr("width", window.innerWidth).attr("height",window.innerHeight)
  .datum(data).call(init());

  function init() {
    var svg, margin = {top: 60,bottom: 80,left: 60,right: 0}, width = 500, height = 400,
      xaxis1 = d3.svg.axis(), xaxis2 = d3.svg.axis(), 
    scaleOne = d3.scale.linear(), scaleTwo = d3.scale.linear(), zoomable = true,
    zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().x(scaleOne).on("zoom", draw)

    svg = d3.select('svg').data([data]);
    svg.enter().append('svg');
    var g = svg.append('g').attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        g.append("defs").append("clipPath")
      .attr("id", "clip")
      .append("rect")
      .attr("width", width - margin.left - margin.right)
      .attr("height", height - margin.top - margin.bottom);

    g.append("svg:rect")
      .attr("class", "border")
      .attr("width", width - margin.left - margin.right)
      .attr("height", height - margin.top - margin.bottom)
      .style("stroke", "black")
      .style("fill", "none");

    g.append("g").attr("class", "axis One")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + (height - margin.top - margin.bottom) + ")");

    g.append("g").attr("class", "axis Two")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + (height - margin.top - margin.bottom + 60) + ")");

    g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "scatter")
      .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");

    g.append("svg:rect")
      .attr("class", "zoom box")
      .attr("width", width - margin.left - margin.right)
      .attr("height", height - margin.top - margin.bottom)
      .style("visibility", "hidden")
      .attr("pointer-events", "all")
      .call(zoom);

    scaleOne.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
      return d[0];
    })).range([0, width - margin.left - margin.right]);

    xaxis1.scale(scaleOne).orient('bottom').tickPadding(10);
    svg.select('g.axis.One').call(xaxis1);

    scaleTwo.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
      return d[1];
    })).range([0, width - margin.left - margin.right]);

    xaxis2.scale(scaleOne)
                .orient('bottom').tickPadding(10)
                .tickFormat(function(d) { return d + 5.5; })
    svg.select('g.axis.Two').call(xaxis2);
    draw();

    function update() {
      var gs = svg.select("g.scatter");
      var circle = gs.selectAll("circle")
        .data(function(d) { return d; });

      circle.enter().append("svg:circle")
        .attr("class", "points")
        .style("fill", "gray")
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return X1(d); })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return X2(d); })
        .attr("r", 4);

      circle.attr("cx", function(d) { return X1(d); })
              .attr("cy", function(d) { return X2(d); });

      circle.exit().remove();
    }

    function zoom_update() {
      zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
               .x(scaleOne)
               .on("zoom", draw)
      svg.select('rect.zoom.box').call(zoom);
    }

    function draw() {
        svg.select('g.axis.One').call(xaxis1);
      svg.select('g.axis.Two').call(xaxis2);
      update();
      zoom_update();
    };

    function X1(d) {
      return scaleOne(d[0]);
    }
    function X2(d) {
      return scaleTwo(d[1]);
    }
    return chart;
  }
```

I took the base code from D3 examples: http://bl.ocks.org/jgbos/9752277